# QGis overlap labels

Tags: qgis

I have a csv file imported into QGis 1.8 and this layer is receiving real time data.Into this attribute table layer there is a field which values i use to label it but overlapping all values when showing.
Is there any way to label only the last record when the attribute table is updating?.

Comment: So you have many records but you only want to show the last one?

Comment: Yes,could be posible?

Comment: Do you have a date stamp on each record?

Comment: Yes,three fields(Long - Lat - Data) and one more from GobetWino with date stamp in each record.